# Not able to add user to SharePoint Group using Rest Api

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, rest, sharepoint-designer

I have been trying to add users through rest api. It says user doesn't exist or not unique all the time

here is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>

var executor;
                       executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(siteUrl);
                       executor.executeAsync({
                       url: siteUrl+"/_api/web/sitegroups("+groupid+")/users?@target='"+siteUrl+"'",
                       method: "POST",
                       body: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'i:0#.w|domain\\ userloginname' }),
                       headers: {
                       "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                       "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                       },
                       success:function(data)
                       {
                       alert("New User:"+email+" added successfully in SharePoint Group: "+groupid);
                     
                       },
                       error: function(err)
                       {
                                                                              console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                       alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                       }
                       });
```

my login name is = userfirstname userlastname like (John Stkeas)

this is the error i get all the time

{"responseAvailable":true,"body":"{"error":{"code":"-2130575276, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The user does not exist or is not unique."}}}","statusCode":404,"statusText":"Not Found","contentType":"application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8","allResponseHeaders":"

I tried replacing it with an email address (example.com) and following names as well still don't work

- i:0#.w|domain\userloginname

This is in SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same LoginName `i:0#.w|domain\userloginname` works for me.

I would suggest you use the endpoint `/_api/web/siteusers?$select=LoginName` to check what your login name is.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, none of the users who have full control and part of the owners for the group are able to add users. They all receive similar errors. I can add and i have the same permission as them. this si very weird.